# Cursor state, C++ concurrency and SQL server

Tags: c++, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures, odbc

So I've been working on this pet-project of mine a few weeks now on my spare-time and have happened across an issue that I'm stuck on. I've looked through SO and Googled the issue, finding nothing that really relates to my specific issue.

I'm running a multi-threaded (I'm very new to multi-threading in c++) that uses a ODBC driver to connect to a local SQL Server instance. 
The connection is working fine and using everything on **the main thread** is fine. However, when I start using multiple threads (as mentioned above, it looks like shit - I'm learning by trial and error) I'm getting error messages that I think have to do with the c++ concurrencty and the stored procedure I'm running on the SQL server.

**The error message as displayed by show_error:**

[image]
**This is the stored procedure:**

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_addHistorical]    Script Date: 30/03/2016 10:16:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_addHistorical]
    @Symbol nchar(10),@Date datetime,
    @Open decimal(12,2),@Close decimal(12,2),@MinPrice decimal(12,2),
    @MaxPrice decimal(12,2),@Volume int
AS 
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    MERGE HistoricalStock WITH (UPDLOCK) AS myTarget
        USING (SELECT @Symbol AS Symbol,
        @Date AS Date, @Open AS [Open], @Close AS [Close],
        @MinPrice AS MinPrice, @MaxPrice AS MaxPrice,@Volume AS Volume) AS mySource
        ON mySource.Symbol = myTarget.Symbol AND mySource.Date = myTarget.Date
        WHEN MATCHED 
            THEN UPDATE 
                SET [Open] = mySource.[Open], [Close] = mySource.[Close],
                MinPrice = mySource.MinPrice, MaxPrice = mySource.MaxPrice, Volume = mySource.Volume            
        WHEN NOT MATCHED
            THEN
                INSERT(Symbol,Date,[Open],[Close],MinPrice,MaxPrice,Volume)
                VALUES(@Symbol,@Date,@Open,@Close,@MinPrice,@MaxPrice,@Volume);
    COMMIT
```

**Below is the database connector and the shitty threading:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "database_con.h"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Show errors from the SQLHANDLE

void database_con::show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        wcout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}

std::wstring database_con::StringToWString(const std::string& s)
{
    std::wstring temp(s.length(), L' ');
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), temp.begin());
    return temp;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Builds the stored procedure query.

std::wstring database_con::buildQuery(vector<std::wstring> input, string symbol)
{
    std::wstringstream builder;
    builder << L"EXEC sp_addHistorical " << "@Symbol='" << L"" << StringToWString(symbol) << "'," <<
        "@Date='" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(0) << "'," <<
        "@Open=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(1) << "," <<
        "@Close=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(2) << "," <<
        "@MaxPrice=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(3) << "," <<
        "@MinPrice=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(4) << "," <<
        "@Volume=" << (wstring)L"" << input.at(5) << ";";
    return builder.str();
}

void database_con::executeQuery(wstring query) {

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirectW(stmt, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(query.c_str()), SQL_NTS)) {
        std::cout << "Execute error " << std::endl;
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        std::wcout << L"Unsuccessful Query: " << query << std::endl;
    }
    // Close Cursor before next iteration starts:
    SQLRETURN closeCursRet = SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(closeCursRet))
    {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
        // maybe add some handling for the case that closing failed.
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Constructs a database connector object with the historical data and its symbol

database_con::database_con(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> historical, string symbol){
    /*
    Set up the handlers
    */

    /* Allocate an environment handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    /* We want ODBC 3 support */
    SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    /* Allocate a connection handle */
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);

    /* Connect to the DSN */
    SQLDriverConnectW(dbc, NULL, L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ERA-PC-STUART\\JBK_DB;DATABASE=master;UID=geo;PWD=kalle123;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
    /* Check for success */
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt))
    {
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc);
        std::cout << "Failed to connect";
    }
    std::cout << "Building and executing the query" << std::endl;

    for (_mVecHistIter = historical.begin();
        _mVecHistIter != historical.end();
        _mVecHistIter+5) {
        std::thread t(&database_con::executeQuery, *this, buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol));
        std::thread t2(&database_con::executeQuery, *this, buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol));
        std::thread t3(&database_con::executeQuery, *this, buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol));
        std::thread t4(&database_con::executeQuery, *this, buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol));
        std::thread t5(&database_con::executeQuery, *this, buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol));
        t.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();

        //executeQuery(buildQuery(*_mVecHistIter, symbol)); 

    }

    /*_mSymbol = symbol;
    std::wstringstream stream(StringToWString(historical));
    std::wstring line;
    int row = 0;
    while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
        if (row > 0) {
            vector<wstring> vHistorical = parseData(L"" + line, ',');
            std::wstring SQL = buildQuery(vHistorical, _mSymbol);
            if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirectW(stmt, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(SQL.c_str()), SQL_NTS)) {
                std::cout << "Execute error " << std::endl;
                show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
                std::wcout << L"Unsuccessful Query: " << SQL << std::endl;
            }
            // Close Cursor before next iteration starts:
            SQLRETURN closeCursRet = SQLFreeStmt(stmt, SQL_CLOSE);
            if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(closeCursRet))
            {
                show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
                // maybe add some handling for the case that closing failed.
            }
        }
        row++;
    }*/
    std::cout << "Query " << _mSymbol << " ready" << std::endl;

}

database_con::~database_con() {
    std::cout << "The database object has been deleted" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason for the errors could be that all your threads use the same statement-handle. The first thread will open a cursor on that statement handle by executing a query. While the query is running, another thread opens a query on the same statement handle, which will probably invalidate the results of the first thread.

I would try to make every thread use its own statement handle, by changing your `executeQuery` to something like:

```
void database_con::executeQuery(wstring query)
{
    // Allocate a new statement to be used:
    SQLHSTMT localStmt = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &localStmt);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        // show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, localStmt);
        // would need some show_error that can work with the dbc handle,
        // as the stmt-handle is invalid and therefore no error info can
        // be fetched
        std::cout << "Allocating stmt handle failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    // Do the work on that statement now
    ret = SQLExecDirectW(localStmt, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(query.c_str()), SQL_NTS);
    if(!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
    {
        std::cout << "Execute error " << std::endl;
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, localStmt);
        std::wcout << L"Unsuccessful Query: " << query << std::endl;
    }
    // And finally free the statement created for this thread
    ret = SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, localStmt);
    if (!SQL_SUCCESS(ret))
    {
        std::cout << L"Freeing thread handle failed" << std::endl;
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, localStmt);
    }
}
```